# What is the benefit of using a TextReader/Writer instead of a Binary Reader/Writer for string data?

Tags: c#, string, text, encoding, stream

Is it correct to assume the only difference here is that Binary Reader/Writer use a fixed-length encoding for strings, and therefore may be less efficient?

Comment: They are different types for different purposes. What are you trying to do?

Comment: As I understand it, I can use a Binary Reader/Writer for handling text files (a bunch of which I'm working with at the moment). Just wondering why I'd ever need a TextReader/Writer instead. In either case I want to load the data into a string, modify it, and write it back.

Comment: You would normally use `BinaryReader/BinaryWriter` for *binary* files (hence the name) even though they may contain text as well. If you're *just* dealing with text, you should use a `TextReader`/`TextWriter`, e.g. `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter`. Note that when you call `BinaryWriter.WriteString` it adds a length prefix - the result won't be a plain text file. You *could* just use `WriteChars` repeatedly, but that would be more awkward.

Answer (score 4):

No there are a bucket load of other differences, e.g. read and writeline, encoding... Basically loads of 'helper' functions that pertain to text.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that regular text files *aren't full of length prefixes*. If you are writing a file that is intended to be read as text: use a TextWriter.

You might think that "ah, and BinaryWriter is for binary", but that isn't really true: BinaryWriter and BinaryReader are paired to eachother, but there is no "general" specification for writing text data in a binary file. It would entirely depend on the file format / protocol, and in most binary cases BinaryWriter is no use whatsoever. More commonly you just use Stream when dealing with binary data.